# Traer todos los datos relacionados de mi categoría en LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

les explico mi problema.
estoy creando una web que va a subir películas, y necesito que al seleccionar la categoría esta me lleve a todas las películas relacionadas con esa categoría.

Esta es la función del controlador.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $categoria = Categoria::find($id);
    return view('categorias.show',compact('categoria','cate'));
}
```

Y esta la vista

```
@foreach ($categoria as $cat)
{{ $cat->nombre }}
 @foreach ($cat->peliculas as $pelicula)
     {{ $pelicula->nombre }}
 @foreach
@endforeach
```

Pero no realiza el recorrido, y me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no es m[as que un simple error tipográfico: no se está cerrando el foreach anidado, o sea debería ser `@endforeach` en la penúltima línea del código mostrado.

Comment: Shaz tiene razon, pero de cualquier forma, seria bueno que muestres el modelo Categoria para estar seguros de tu relación.